Can a "Polearm master" with "mastery" of their weapon use the mastery property with the 1d4 bonus action?
It seems to me that the PHP 2024 rules are ambiguous on this question, or at least, my rules-as-written interpretation is very counter-intuitive:

Mastery Properties
Each weapon has a mastery property, which is usable only by a character who has a feature, such as Weapon Mastery, that unlocks the property for the character. The properties are defined below.


Polearm Master
[...] Pole Strike. Immediately after you take the Attack action and attack with a Quarterstaff, a Spear, or a weapon that has the Heavy and Reach properties, you can use a Bonus Action to make a melee attack with the opposite end of the weapon. The weapon deals Bludgeoning damage, and the weapon’s damage die for this attack is a d4.[...]

To me, this says nothing about mastery properties, and thus the weapon's normal property (e.g. "push" for a pike) would apply to the bonus action attack as well. Simple, logical interpretation of the rules. I suspect this is the RAW answer.
On the other hand, common sense tells me that based on the description ("opposite end of the weapon") and damage type (bludgeoning), it would make no sense at all for e.g. a glaive, where the bonus action would do "graze" damage with what is essentially a weaker quarterstaff attack.
If anything, the common sense answer is to consider the BA attack as having the "topple" property, since that's what a quarterstaff has. Then again, it makes just as much sense to imagine that it has no mastery property at all, since it's a secondary attack and something of an "improvised weapon" after all. THEN AGAIN, the feat says "mastery" right there in the title!
Anyway, if anyone has a clarification from the designers, that would be ideal, since this strikes me as an "unstated intent" scenario. If they said "the extra attack has no mastery property because it is not the same attack as the one listed in the equipment chart", that could make sense, though without that clarification, it seems like DMs are going to have to decide for themselves, and the default will be the illogical conclusion that I can graze my enemies with a piece of flat wood ‍♀️

You mention and quote 2024, but tagged it 2014.

This actually pretty similar to using a normal weapon as an improvised weapon.  You can hit with the hilt of a shortsword dealing 1d4 Bludgeoning damage, even without needing a feat and the rules for improvised weapon's don't mentioned weapon mastery at all, so whatever the answer to this is will almost certainly also apply to normal weapons being used as improvised weapons.

@TreeSpawned The new "Improvised Weapon" rules say the DM picks the damage type, and also that you can't use your proficiency bonus. They're comparable, but seem distinct enough that the rule wouldn't apply. Personally as DM I'd say an improvised weapon just doesn't get mastery properties at all, except maybe if the "equivalent weapon" clause applies, like the example given of a table leg being equivalent to a club. But to me if it was that similar, I'd say "It's a club." rather than "it's an improvised weapon".

Mastery Property is just another property of a weapon, like Reach, Heavy, etc. Polearm Master just gives another way to attack with that weapon, not creates a new one. So, all properties of weapon remain - bonus attack with Glaive, for example, would still have Reach, would still be done with disadvantage, if character lacks Strength to wield it and still would Graze opponent if missed.
It's pretty similar to Thrown weapons - whether character strikes with them  or throws it - they still can use Mastery Property.

Absent a clarification, I guess we can graze people with the butt of our glaives ‍♀️ I'd definitely consider overriding this absurdity as a DM.

As a GM - you are free to invent your own homerules. But RAW, there is NO indication that Mastery Property is different from any other properties of weapon (except activation condition). Also, there is no indication that attack with "opposite end of the weapon" would not use properties of the weapon.
